# ReadOnly state when I need to change it

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code and I really need to be able to change the state however I am having issues when I try and do the following.

```
export default class Mediaplayer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: [],
      station: null,
      playButton: false,
      muteButton: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { station, playButton, muteButton } = this.state;
    const handleMClick = (e) => {
      // Event("Play Button", "Listner Hit Play", "PLAY_BUTTON");
      console.log("clicking the play and pause button");

      this.setState({ playButton: !playButton });
      playButton
        ? document.getElementById("player").play()
        : document.getElementById("player").pause();
    };

    return (
      <i onClick={handleMClick}>
        {playButton ? <PlayCircle size={60} /> : <PauseCircle size={60} />}
      </i>
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting this state is ReadOnly.

Comment: Any particular reason for using a class component instead of a functional component? Doing dom query in react is not a recommended way of doing things. but try to put player play() pause() code like this. `this.setState({playButton: !playButton}, () => { // Logic here})`. That means seconds argument of the `setState()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `setState()` only takes effect after the whole eventHandler is
  finished, this is called [state batching](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).
- Your `this.setState({playButton:!playButton})` only run after `handleMClick()` is finished.
- In other words, `playButton === true`  will not available within your `handleMClick()` function.

**On solution could be to put this**:

```
playButton ? document.getElementById("player").play() : document.getElementById("player").pause()
```

Inside a `componentDidUpdate()` so it will take effect in the next render after your state is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Direct dom manipulation is not a recommended way of doing things in react because you can always change dom element state according to your react component state or props.

I see your component is called media player but it doesn't have the `#player` inside it? Perhaps you could reconsider how you arranging the dom element.

Also try to use a functional component instead of class component. I will give an answer with a functional component.

### MediaPlayer Component

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const MediaPlayer = props => {
   const [play, setPlay] = useState(false);
   const togglePlay = () => {
       setPlay( !play );
   }
    return (
        <i onClick={togglePlay}>                                              
          {!play ? 
               <PlayCircle size={60}/> 
              :  
              <PauseCircle size={60}/>}</i>
          }
    );
}
```